# History navigation in Vi mode of Bash shell

Tags: bash, shell, keyboard-shortcuts, command-history, vi

When I switch to `vi` mode in shell (`bash` or `ksh`) very useful to me shortcuts such as <kbd>C-p</kbd> and <kbd>C-n</kbd> to go back and forth in command history disappear. I don't want to rely on <kbd>Up</kbd> and <kbd>Down</kbd> for that. I don't want to add key bindings every time for every shell. I just want to know if there's alternative native Vi mode commands for navigation in history.

---

Btw, <kbd>C-l</kbd> for clearing screen disappear too, is there a default key binding for clearing the screen in Vi mode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default key-bindings for moving up or down in the command history in all shells that I know of that supports Vi key-bindings is <kbd>k</kbd> for the previous command and <kbd>j</kbd> for the next command.

These are the same as the corresponding movement commands in the Vi editor.

For them to work, you will have to be in "normal" mode, i.e. you have to press <kbd>Esc</kbd> once.

To clear the screen, use the command `clear`.

Comment: Thank you. I assume I can't navigate through history while in `insert` mode.

Comment: @Chinggis6 In insert mode, the previous and next item in the command line history is bound to the up and down arrow keys (as in "normal" mode). As far as I know, `bash` does not by default add any other key-mapping for this in Vi insert mode.

Comment: You could use Ctrl+[ instead of Esc to switch to normal mode (it works in bash vi mode and in vim by default). I find it a lot quicker then moving to Esc.